# how to install gcc compiler on red hat linux without internet connection?

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat, rpm, yum

I want to install gcc compiler in the Redhat Linux VM where internet connection is not available. Using Scp software i'm downloading rpm  files and moving to the VM. I would like to know what all are dependent rpm files for gcc to get installed. I dont want to build gcc as I'm new to the Linux.

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

`yum` manual:

> **deplist**
>
> Produces a list of all dependencies and what packages provide those dependencies for the given packages.

Try somenthing like:

```
$ yum deplist gcc
```

Output:

```
package: gcc.x86_64 4.8.5-4.el7
  dependency: /bin/sh
   provider: bash.x86_64 4.2.46-20.el7_2
  dependency: /sbin/install-info
   provider: info.x86_64 5.1-4.el7
  dependency: binutils >= 2.20.51.0.2-12
   provider: binutils.x86_64 2.23.52.0.1-55.el7
  dependency: cpp = 4.8.5-4.el7
   provider: cpp.x86_64 4.8.5-4.el7
  dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12
   provider: glibc-devel.x86_64 2.17-106.el7_2.8
   provider: glibc-devel.i686 2.17-106.el7_2.8
  dependency: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-106.el7_2.8
  dependency: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-106.el7_2.8
  dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-106.el7_2.8
  dependency: libdl.so.2()(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-106.el7_2.8
  dependency: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-106.el7_2.8
  dependency: libgcc >= 4.8.5-4.el7
   provider: libgcc.x86_64 4.8.5-4.el7
   provider: libgcc.i686 4.8.5-4.el7
  dependency: libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: libgcc.x86_64 4.8.5-4.el7
  dependency: libgmp.so.10()(64bit)
   provider: gmp.x86_64 1:6.0.0-12.el7_1
  dependency: libgomp = 4.8.5-4.el7
   provider: libgomp.x86_64 4.8.5-4.el7
   provider: libgomp.i686 4.8.5-4.el7
  dependency: libgomp.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: libgomp.x86_64 4.8.5-4.el7
  dependency: libm.so.6()(64bit)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-106.el7_2.8
  dependency: libmpc.so.3()(64bit)
   provider: libmpc.x86_64 1.0.1-3.el7
  dependency: libmpfr.so.4()(64bit)
   provider: mpfr.x86_64 3.1.1-4.el7
  dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: zlib.x86_64 1.2.7-15.el7
  dependency: rtld(GNU_HASH)
   provider: glibc.x86_64 2.17-106.el7_2.8
   provider: glibc.i686 2.17-106.el7_2.8
```

Hope It Helps!

Comment: I'm getting the following error when i run this command:

"Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
*Note* Red Hat Network repositories are not listed below. You must run this comm  and as root to access RHN repositories.
Finding dependencies:"

Comment: try: `sudo yum deplist gcc`

Comment: this also didnt work for me @Lacobus